# How to store camera stream data in an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling, directshow, ram

I need to store five minutes of streaming data in **RAM** (or an alternative, if such available. Now I only know of **RAM**).
I know how to convert the data into bmp images and store them in an list using the bytes, using `Marshal.copy`

But the size of each frame is about 3Mb, which is too big for **RAM** to store.

I believe, the size of the data could be much smaller, if I simply stored the bytes in an array, but I dont know how. The whole Marshal thing is not very clear to me at this moment and days of searching for methods to copy pointer value to managed array was in vain.
I need help.

What am I missing? 
Why I can not copy the chunk I can use to store as BMP, as simple array of bytes?
How can I convert the following function to one that returns array?

Here is the code I am using to convert the data into BMP, and I need be able to make necessary changes to convert it to a function that collects all data as it is in a list or array.

```
private Bitmap GetBitmap(ISampleGrabber i_grabber, int width, int height, int stride)
    {
        int sz = 0;
        i_grabber.GetCurrentBuffer(ref sz, IntPtr.Zero); 
        if (sz == 0) return null;
        var ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(sz);
        i_grabber.GetCurrentBuffer(ref sz, ptr);
        var data = new byte[sz];
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, data, 0, sz);
        Bitmap result = null;
        try
        {
            result = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            var bmp_data = result.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, result.Size), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                var src_idx = sz - (stride * (y + 1));
                //Console.WriteLine(src_idx);
                var dst = new IntPtr(bmp_data.Scan0.ToInt32() + (stride * y));
                Marshal.Copy(data, src_idx, dst, stride);
            }

            result.UnlockBits(bmp_data);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ax)
        {
            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ax.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ax.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What kind of resolution are you using? Meaning image width and height in pixels, as well as color resolution, 24bit?

Comment: 1280x720, 15 FPS, 24Bit MPEG

Comment: If it is MPEG, why are you dealing with BMP? Shouldn't you be able to store the MPEG stream? This should take vastly less memory than the raw still images. The still images alone would be 1280x720x15x60x5x3 (3 = 24-bit) = 12.4 GB.

Comment: But for some reason, directly adding the bytes to the video riff file is causing size getting too large. In fact, a lot larger than BMP fed to AviWriter. 

It seems, I have to stick to graph with file writer sink.

Answer (score 0):

3 megabytes per frame, 300 seconds and N frames per second are likely to make it too big for RAM anyway. You have to do something with the data as video capture goes.

Some ideas for you:

1. Compression - if you can compress the data in real time, your storage requirements will be significantly reduced, including affording storage of 300 seconds in RAM, maybe even with lossless encoding

1.1. Hardware assisted compression (requires GPU, in some cases can be lossless); the output will be fine for RAM and for disk writing

1.2. Software compression with well known format (high CPU load); the data will fit RAM

1.3. Some lightweight compression using simple well known algorithm, may be lossless; depending on content it is quite likely that even simple post-processing reduces amount of data to keep

2. Asynchronous disk writing - if you write as you capture, the amount of data can be too large to write to temporary disk location in real time but writing asynchronously without blocking capture can take you to the point where you flush enough data to disk and the remainder of the data fits available RAM by the fifth minute of video capture.

Comment: 3Mb per frame is a result of BMP conversion. How can I get the frame data into bytes and add to a List?

Comment: In the comment above you mention "MPEG". It is not MPEG, is it? I guess it is M-JPEG. In this case it would make sense to keep M-JPEG format and 300 seconds of such stream could fit RAM, or otherwise it would be fairly simple to write to disk as capture goes. Decompression from M-JPEG is apparently making it much larger (BMP).

Comment: Exactly! The graph is adding the M-JPEG decompressor filter, but as the samplegrabber is added right before that filter, it is possible to retrieve the data as is.
And I need to learn how to store that data as it is in RAM.
Can you help with the unmanaged byte array pointer to managed array/list conversion?

Comment: Graph manager would add decompression if you setup sample grabber to receive RGB. Similarly you can have it receive MJPEG and SampleCB callback would have data bytes that represent video frame in JPEG format. You would process the data the same way copying it out of internal buffer to safe place. Later you can use JPEG bytes to decompress into BMP or similar.

Comment: I tried storing the bytes in RAM. The size was about 300Mb per 20 secs. At 15 fps, that makes roughly 1Mb per frame. Which is a lot better, but still too big.

Comment: 1 MB sounds like too much for 1280x720 JPEG, I'd double check that. It should be like ten times more compact. Then you'd perhaps want to control JPEG compression on the camera itself to make sure the setting is reasonable there.

Comment: When I simply use file sink to record the video with those settings, I get 53Mb per minute. So it makes no sense how byte array can be so fat.

Comment: 53 MB/min sounds about right. I guess that you make multiple copies of the same frame with `GetCurrentBuffer` calls. It is generally not a good idea to go that way. Check out Sample Grabber `SampleCB` callback to see how grab frames accurately.

Comment: However, I was able to save those frames as video without problems. Of course the size was according to the custom writer I was using in this case, AviWriter. 

I have just customized and tried using the SampleCB callback method from CAMERA_NET CameraControlTool sample project. I was getting the same size.

The last commit has all changes
https://github.com/digitalprojections/Camera_Net

Comment: Maybe you could create such overly large clip of 10 seconds (so that it's not really huge) and attach it to this question. It's hard to guess what you are doing wrong which results in huge output.